# HttpFileCollection always returns count > 0

Tags: asp.net

I have a form with 1 input type="file" element. I would expect that when no file is selected, in the code behind the collection of HttpFileCollection would be empty.

However it seems that the count is always greater than zero.

as demonstrated with the following code:

```
Dim files As HttpFileCollection = Request.Files

        If files.Count > 0 Then
           'At least one file has been uploaded
        End if
```

Am I experiencing a general quirk, or is this expected behavior?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

In your .aspx page:-

```
     <form id="form1" runat="server" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input type="file" id="myFile" name="myFile" />
     <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnUpload" OnClick="btnUploadClick" Text="Upload" />
     </form>
```

In your Code Behind File

```
        protected void btnUploadClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpPostedFile file = Request.Files["myFile"];

            //check file was submitted
            if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
               {
                   string fname = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                   file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(Path.Combine("~/App_Data/", fname)));
                }
         }
```

Comment: it is in c#, I believe it will be fine for  u

Comment: It is working perfect dude...why did you voted down my answer?